# MySQL GROUP BY data and separating grouped data into columns

Tags: mysql

I have a bus_pings table:

```
CREATE TABLE bus_pings(
    id int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ping_time DATETIME(3),
    line INT(10),
    speed DECIMAL(3,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**I want to get the average speed grouped by date and with separated columns for each distinct line.**
Like this:

```
DATE    LINE_74 LINE_96 LINE_86 LINE_91
2017-10-15  14,2868246445   14,719426483    16,1636562671   15,5332546242
2017-10-16  13,1164417178   14,214340589    14,7644345606   13,3649570639
2017-10-17  11,6387929133   12,2247682434   12,7987289148   11,5381412639
```

I can get the speed average for just one line with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(ping_time, '%Y-%m-%d'), AVG(speed) as speed_average
FROM bus_pings
WHERE line=74
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ping_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I have many bus lines, I need to consult all the lines in a single query. Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: Scalability, flexibility, and ease. Are any of those special?

Comment: Scalability is importante for me I have more 100 millions of pings. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(ping_time, '%Y-%m-%d'),
    AVG(CASE WHEN line=74 THEN speed END) AS line_74_avg,
    AVG(CASE WHEN line=96 THEN speed END) AS line_96_avg,
    AVG(CASE WHEN line=86 THEN speed END) AS line_86_avg,
    AVG(CASE WHEN line=91 THEN speed END) AS line_91_avg
FROM bus_ping
WHERE line IN (74, 96, 86, 91)
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(ping_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The basic idea here is to make a single pass over your table and conditionally take the average of the various lines using a `CASE` expression.

Comment: Okay Tim, this is working fine! But in case I have more than a hundred bus lines. Is there any way to do a subquery to minimize this code?

Comment: @AlexandreStrapacaoG.Vianna Then you probably need dynamic SQL to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a valid query...

```
SELECT line
     , DATE_FORMAT(ping_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
     , AVG(speed) speed_average
  FROM bus_pings
 GROUP 
    BY line
     , DATE_FORMAT(ping_time, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

EVERYTHING else should be handled in application code.